# Change suiteBar navigation items

Tags: suite-links

SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2013 On-premise has on top by default blue track with some links (Outlook, People, SkyDrive, Sites). In HTML it is shown as id="suiteBar" .Is it possible to customize this menu / navigation on SharePoint 2013 on-premise ? If so, how and where, I want to add some fix links and remove some them.

For example, my on-premise does not contain info from Exchange (Mail, People etc.), how to add them, is it IT stuff or development with JavaScript ?

Comment: This doable in SharePoint 2016. https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt790697(v=office.16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that here is nice blog about this which explains everything - http://academy.bindtuning.com/customize-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-suite-bar/

Answer (score 2):

The Suite Links are customizable with a SharePoint Delegate Control.  I wrote a post a while back on how to create a delegate control that replaces the default links with a control that keeps the existing ones while adding your own: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2013-adding-links-suite-bar-newsfeed-skydrive-sites-overriding-suitelinksdelegate-delegate-control/

Comment: So it must be developers and IT stuff can not easly change this using sharepoint powershell for example.

Comment: No, not with PowerShell.  You can either go the delegate control method, use jQuery to do it after the page loads (in a content editor web part), or modify the master page (hide the existing control and put your own HTML in its place).

Comment: I just need to append some static tags after the original HTML. Isn't there a simpler way to just capture whole of default HTML and append my tags to it when the control is rendering.

Comment: @JohnChapman, the url given by you is broken